# How to access request attributes in freemarker template in Liferay 7

Tags: liferay, freemarker, liferay-7

I'm editing my custome Liferay theme's template and I would like to access request attributes.

In jsp file I can write:

```
request.getAttribute(ProductNavigationUserPersonalBarWebKeys.NOTIFICATIONS_COUNT)
```

I would like to get the same in freemarker template. I've tried something like this:

```
request.attributes.NOTIFICATIONS_COUNT
```

but I'm getting:

```
freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException: The following has evaluated to null or missing
```

Anyone can help me?

Comment: What is the value of `ProductNavigationUserPersonalBarWebKeys.NOTIFICATIONS_COUNT` constant?

Comment: That's string "NOTIFICATIONS_COUNT".

Comment: Then, `${Request['NOTIFICATIONS_COUNT']}` or `${Request.NOTIFICATIONS_COUNT}` should work.

Comment: I've already tried this. Unfortunately it doesn't work: `The following has evaluated to null or missing`.

Comment: Then you might require to add add `null` check :p

Comment: But it shouldn't be null. I can include in the template `user_personal_bar` jsp and there calling `request.getAttribute(ProductNavigationUserPersonalBarWebKeys.NOTIFICATIONS_COUNT)` returns proper value.

Comment: http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web/23988-how-to-access-request-parameters-in-freemarker

Comment: I've tried possible solutions from that thread, no results.

Comment: You should include the full error message when you try these dotted things, because what's null or missing in it matters. Like in the original attempt, is it the `request`, or `request.attributes` or `request.attributes.NOTIFICATIONS_COUNT`? Similarly, in your later attempts, does `Request` (with capital `R`) exist, and only `Request.NOTIFICATIONS_COUNT` is missing?